# Undefined reference to cpp function while using Swig and setuptools

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, swig

I'm trying to use C++ from Python with SWIG, starting with a simple example. All my files are in the same directory.

example.cpp

```
double add_from_c(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

example.h

```
double add_from_c(double, double);
```

example.i

```
%module example_from_c
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup

setup(
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            name="example_from_c",
            sources=["example.i"],
        ),
    ]
)
```

Terminal command

```
python setup.py build_ext
```

Error:

```
...
...
C:\Users\xxx/example_wrap.c:2777: undefined reference to `add_from_c'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\xxx\\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Python version: 3.10

Answer (score 0):

The function in example.h should be declared with C linkage

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double add_from_c(double, double);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Otherwise, if C linkage is not required, it would raise the error

```
C:\Users\xxx/example_wrap.c:2777: undefined reference to `add_from_c(double, double)'
```

Comment: This created another error: it says 2 things: `example.h:1:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant extern "C" double add_from_c(double, double);`  and `example_wrap.c:2777:20: warning: implicit declaration of function 'add_from_c'; did you mean '_wrap_add_from_c'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 2777 |   result = (double)add_from_c(arg1,arg2);`

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer, I missed its another inclusion into the C file example_wrap.c.

Comment: Back to the original error. Actually it says exactly what you say it would raise

Comment: if you get this, then some of .cpp doesn't seem to include example.h.